# Regex for beautify text

Tags: php, regex

I would like to create a function that beautify my text. For this I use a regex who remplace some characters, but it not run. Can you give me the regular expression for this :

- Replace the first letter by a caps
- Replace any underscore _ by a space

So for example: the_pack_2 will be The pack 2.
Thx

Answer (score 1):

No need for regex here.

```
$foo = 'the_pack_2';
$foo = ucfirst($foo); // The_pack_2
$foo = str_replace("_", " ", $foo); // The pack 2
```